# Another problem with ages

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, meta-knowledge

Remember the famous three kids problem with the oldest one who plays the piano? Take a look at the next one:

> A priest and a verger were travelling on a train carriage with three more passengers.
> Then the priest said to the verger: *"The product of those three passengers ages is 2450 and the sum is twice your age. How old are they?"*
> The verger made some mental calculation and replied to the priest that he didn't give him enough information to solve the problem.
> *"Very well!"* - replied the priest - *"One of all of you is older than everyone else!"* - and the verger solved the problem.

How old are the priest, the verger and the three other passengers?

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot about the priest

Comment: @hexomino, bingo! ;)

Comment: Very clever twist on a classic puzzle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution

> $$2450 = 2 \times 5^2 \times 7^2$$ which means that the three other passenger ages must be one of the following $$\{1,1,2450\}, \{1,2,1225\}, \{1,5,490\}, \{1,7,350\}, \{1,10,245\}, \{1,14,175\}, \{1,25,98\},$$ $$\{1,35,70\}, \{1,49,50\}, \{2,5,245\}, \{2,7,175\}, \{2,25,49\}, \{2,35,35\}, \{5,5,98\}, $$ $$\{5,7,70\}, \{5,10,49\}, \{5,14,35\}, \{7,7,50\}, \{7,10,35\}, \{7,14,25\}$$ which makes the sums of the ages one of the following $$2452, 1228, 496, 358, 256, 190, 124, 106, 100, 252, 184, 76, 72, 104, 82, \mathbf{64}, 54, \mathbf{64}, 52, 46$$ We notice that $64$ is the only possibility that appears twice so it is the only possibility that can confound the verger's calculation.
>  This means that the verger is **32**
>  Furthermore, the passenger ages must either be $\{5,10,49\}$ or $\{7,7,50\}$.
>  Given the last statement the verger must know the priest's age and can only know the answer for definite if the priest is **49** (if the priest is older then the statement is false, younger and the verger cannot deduce the ages) which makes the passenger ages **7,7** and **50**.

Comment: You got the tricky part. The "everyone else" includes the priest! Well done!